# Excel Automation - how to just say No

Tags: vb.net, excel, automation, interop, excel-interop

I'm working on a vb.net console app that opens a number of spreadsheets one by one, reads in a couple cells and closes the file.

Some of the spreadsheets have formulas that Excel recalculates when I open the file, and I'm getting a dialog box asking me if I want to save changes to the spreadsheet when I close it.

Message: "Do you want to save the changes to myfile.xls?  Microsoft Office Excel recalculates formulas when opening files last saved by an earlier version of Excel"

How do I automatically decline that dialog box?

```
            Dim newCBD As New CBD
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

            xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(myFile)
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

            ...do a bunch of junk here

            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Adding information here, Excel will recalculate formulas automatically if the program version is newer than the file version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to supply a False parameter on the Close method

```
xlWorkBook.Close(False)
```

From Excel VBA Help:

> Close method as it applies to the
>   Workbook object.
>
> Closes the object.
>
> expression.Close(SaveChanges,
>   Filename, RouteWorkbook)
>
> expression   Required. An expression
>   that returns one of the above objects.
>
> SaveChanges  Optional Variant. If
>   there are no changes to the workbook,
>   this argument is ignored. If there are
>   changes to the workbook and the
>   workbook appears in other open
>   windows, this argument is ignored. If
>   there are changes to the workbook but
>   the workbook doesn't appear in any
>   other open windows, this argument
>   specifies whether changes should be
>   saved, as shown in the following
>   table.
>
> Value Action  True Saves the changes
>   to the workbook. If there is not yet a
>   file name associated with the
>   workbook, then FileName is used. If
>   FileName is omitted, the user is asked
>   to supply a file name.  False Does not
>   save the changes to this file. 
>   Omitted Displays a dialog box asking
>   the user whether or not to save
>   changes.
>
> FileName   Optional Variant. Save
>   changes under this file name.
>
> RouteWorkbook  Optional Variant. If
>   the workbook doesn't need to be routed
>   to the next recipient (if it has no
>   routing slip or has already been
>   routed), this argument is ignored.
>   Otherwise, Microsoft Excel routes the
>   workbook as shown in the following
>   table.
>
> Value Meaning  True Sends the workbook
>   to the next recipient.  False Doesn't
>   send the workbook.  Omitted Displays a
>   dialog box asking the user whether the
>   workbook should be sent.

Answer (score 3):

Per this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223560.aspx

> If you set the Saved  property for a workbook to True without saving the workbook to the disk, Microsoft Excel will quit without asking you to save the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to use [Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.close%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to avoid this error message but what if you are using the version like v11.0 which have [close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.close%28v=office.11%29) that takes no parameter so the problem still does not solve for this case. To deal with this issue you may use  [Marshal.RealeaseCOMObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) BUT remember there are some [issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx) with that.

In response to your "how to just say No", you can use:

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts= false;  // use just above the Close() method calls
xlApp.Workbooks.Close(); // here no arguments can be used.
```

Hope it helps!